# Asp.net Core SendGrid Dynamic Template Integration

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I recently added SendGrid to my .net Core  razor project. In order to make the automated account confirmation and password reset emails more professional I've tried to implement the dynamic templates. Email was working fine before, but as soon as I added the Template ID using the SendGrid helper, the emails won't send.

```
 //string emailString = "<html><body>"
                    //+ "<img src='https://publishendersapp.azwebsites.net/images/logo.png' />"
                    //+ "<p>Dear " + user.FirstName + ",</p>"
                    //    + "<p>Thank you for registering for PublishFinders.com! We are glad to have you on board.</p>"
                    //    + $"Please <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'> click </a> here to confirm your email address. <br />"


                    //    + "<p>Thank you for registering ! </p>"
                    //    + "<p>The PublisherFinders Team</p>" +
                    //    "</body></html>";

                    //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                    //    Input.Email, "Confirm your email ", emailString

                    //    );
```

This code use it's working fine but not working send with Template

Comment: do you get any exceptions? please provide a [mcve]

Comment: We have use this code https://www.vivienfabing.com/dotnetcore/2019/04/14/how-to-send-a-dynamic-email-from-sendgrid-with-dotnet-core.html . But not send email in this case .

Comment: Note- I have make a template in send grid Portal

Comment: it seems it was responded in [question]:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60354527) Check it please

Comment: it seems it was responded in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60354527 Check it please

Comment: It seems it was responded in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60354527 Check it please

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to send the email? And do you get an error when you try to send? Or see any sending errors in the SendGrid dashboard?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/60354527 - I have already check this and no error found

Comment: Any Solution this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me fine:

```
var templateId = "x-xxxxxxxxxx";
var dynamicTemplateData = new { };

// Create a SendGrid E-Mail
var apiKey = _config.GetValue<string>("SendGridKey");
var emailKey = _config.GetValue<string>("Email");
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
EmailAddress feedbackFrom =  new EmailAddress(emailKey, null);

var feedBack = MailHelper.CreateSingleTemplateEmail(feedbackFrom, feedBackTo, templateId, dynamicTemplateData);
var feedBackResponse = await client.SendEmailAsync(feedBack);
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you´re trying to send the email using SMTP. To send mail using Dynamic Templates, you must use the [Web API mail.send](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/v3-mail-send-faq/). SMTP sends do not support Dynamic Templates.

Check out the following link [https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/v3-mail-send-faq/)

Comment: Any other solution for this issue

Comment: We have not use SMTP I'm using Send grid